# SSH socks proxy via jumphost

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, openssh, socks

I am trying to create an SSH socks tunnel between two computers that are both behind firewalls. I have a server with a public IP address that I can use as a jumphost. I made this picture to illustrate what I want.[image: illustration]

I have managed to ssh -R from "computer in another network" to "my server" and I could use CURL to ifconfig.me and it showed me the IP "85.123.12.12" as intended. But I can't manage to do a local port forward from "My computer" to "My server" that would support SOCKS. Am I completely off track? How would you do this?

"My computer" and "computer in another network" are both running windows 10.

"My server" is running the latest version of Ubuntu 20.